# Novel about a man who helps alien fix his spaceship, is claimed as an artist on alien's world

Tags: story-identification, novel

Read an old science fiction story, can’t remember title or author. At least 40 years ago.

A man helps an alien repair and launch his spaceship.  Finds he is on one-way trip to alien world. This world is utopia, but he has no place in it. He recites some poetry and song lyrics, and the aliens are fascinated, thinking he is a genius artist. Artists are highly respected but those who perform others' works are not.  It's a crime to claim others' work.  Story ends, I believe, with him getting caught.

Does anyone recognize this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Alien Planet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11485) by Fletcher Pratt
Humanoid alien crash lands in wilderness where he is found by two hunters, who befriend him. The alien is looking for a chemical element called "pleci", needed by his home planet. The hunters help the alien repair his space ship, financed by synthetic diamonds.

Pleci turns out to be Coronium, available  at the planet Mercury. After many adventures they arrive at the alien's home planet.

The protagonist becomes bored, and translates some Shakespearean poetry into the alien's language, but neglects to tell them he is plagiarizing.

Protagonist gets caught and aliens throw him in jail. They allow him to write his memoir on sheets of metal, and the aliens send them back to Earth in a meteorite